# Nestjs ConfigModule: setting / overriding values in config object

Tags: configuration, nestjs

I am using `ConfigModule` to get config, using custom `load`:

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  isGlobal: true,
  load: [defaultConfig]
}),
```

In my `defaultConfig` I am setting default values if they are missing in `.env` and/or otherwise amending the values:

```
export const defaultConfig = () => {
  return {
    URL_PREFIX: process.env.URL_PREFIX || 'http://localhost:3000',
    MICROSERVICE_URL: process.env.MICROSERVICE_URL + '/api/full/path',
    // .... other values
  };
};
```

The trouble is, when I want to get e.g. `MICROSERVICE_URL` from `ConfigService` I get only the original value set in `.env` file, not the value with full path as set / amended in the `defaultConfig` function:

```
constructor(config: ConfigService) {
  this.API_URL = config.get(`MICROSERVICE_URL`);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or the `ConfigModule` does not override already set variables and I should use some other variable to store changed values? E.g. in `defaultConfig`:

```
MICROSERVICE_URL_FULL: process.env.MICROSERVICE_URL + '/api/full/path',
```

That is my current solution however it introduces many, many new variables that are not really necessary, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason of this behavior is that, **ConfigService of Nestjs** does not overrides the values if the value has the same name as mentioned in **ENV**.

And, I am in **favor of making a new variable**, since in that new variable you can even play with datatype, I mean, you can **change the datatype** and format as well of the env variable and store it for your code, like in case of **PORT value**, if you read directly from env it returns the string (*which is ok for Express to start on*) but incase of boolean variables, its needed to be in boolean otherwise we end up doing **BOOL_VAR === "false"** or otherwise, which I feel is a very ugly code.

**What I did**

---

Created a file that returns a function with the formatted values from the ENV and that too in Grouped fromat like:

**ConfigLoader.js(or ts)**

```
export default () => ({
   // SYSTEM LEVEL CONFIG
   SYSTEM: {
      PORT: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000,
      NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
      SOME_BOOLEAN: JSON.parse(process.env.ANY_BOOLEAN_VAR) || true
   },
});
```

And passed this to ConfigModule in **load** property.

*Note:*

- The variables in the ENV can't be grouped, but we can, like in:  ConfgiLoader.js(or ts)
- I took care of default values too, if not passed **PORT** will take the value 3000
- And NODE_ENV will take the value 'development'
- Also, the port property I changed to Number(Int) which is better than string
- Also, the boolean value is changed to boolean type as well.

Thanks
Happy Coding :)

Comment: The nesting approach neglects the fact that some downstream services (that we might not have control over) are looking for a specific variable at a specific place (e.g., `NODE_ENV`), so at some point you'll have to have a custom logic that places values from `config.SYSTEM.*` directly onto `process.env`. I wish the env-overriding mechanism was built-in in Nest.

Comment: I too agree with you on this, but, its something, which as a developer, we have to remember that we should always use the values from our made up object, and don't use the one from process.env.